# ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1045, 5) instead

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, naive-bayes-classifier, jupyter

I have just started Python and working on training models. The task that I have been assigned is to train a dataset named "austin_Weather"

**[Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4m7E.jpg)**

**[y attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9TVl.jpg)**

After having done some manipulations (following the article), these are my new datasets for training and testing,

**[X Train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dasA.jpg)**

**[y Train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaeDw.png)**

Now, I tried to apply Naive-Baysen algorithm on these two datasets, but I got this following error

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1045, 5) instead.
```

So, I tried searching it up online, and I found one solution that I should reshape these arrays, so I tried the following code,

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
```

But I got this error on this,

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

I tried to fix it up by searching it up online, but I couldn't understand most of the things due to my lack of knowledge in Python syntax. If anyone can help resolve this and tell me what exactly is the problem here, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is *multilabel*: each row can have more than one label. But sklearn's Naive Bayes doesn't support that format of problem. You can use `MultiOutputClassifier` to wrap the Naive Bayes classifier, effectively training one model for each of the labels.

See [the User Guide](https://sklearn.org/modules/multiclass.html), especially the [MultiOutput classification section](https://sklearn.org/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification). You may also want to consider the `ClassifierChain` (in the next section).

---

The last error you see is because you're using pandas structures, but `reshape` is a numpy method. Anyway, as @Oxbowerce observed, reshaping won't help; you need to deal with having multiple labels.

Answer (score 0):

Your y values (i.e. the values that you want to predict) should be a 1d array, meaning that you are only trying to predict one type of value (instead of the 8 values you have in `y_train`). You should therefore select one of those columns as the column you want to predict with the Naive Bayes model.

The suggestion to reshape your array to 1d only really makes sense when you have 1 value you would like to predict but your array still has more than 1 dimension. The reason you are getting the error when reshaping is because `.reshape` is a `numpy` method that does not directly work on `pandas.Series`. Converting the `pandas.Series` to a `numpy.array` before using `.reshape` should work (but this doesn't make sense in your case as explained above, and will likely give other errors your `y` array is now longer than your `X` array).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the reply. But how do I resolve this problem then? can you tell any suitable solution, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Like I said in the first paragraph, simply select just one of the 8 columns from your `y_train` dataframe and using Naive Bayes on this should work fine.